# Aptana Studio 3.3.2 - NO UPDATE SITE

Tags: eclipse, aptana, aptana3

I've just installed Aptana Studio 3.3.2 and clicked *Check for updates* under the *Help* menu.

There came a popup saying

> There are no update sites to search. Do you wish to open the "Available Software Sites" preferences?.
>    NO / YES

Clicking *yes* reveals that there are indeed no sites listed in the Available Software Sites list.

When searching the Internet for the update URL for Aptana Studio, I only found an old URL for Eclipse 3.2.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is going on with your installation, but if you go into `Window > Preferences > Install/Update > Available Software Sites` you can add the Aptana Studio 3 update site: http://download.aptana.com/studio3-rcp/plugin/update/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my install. I went to `Window > Preference > Install/Update > Available Software Sites` and the site should be there, you just need to check it off.

[image]